# Allowing a Javascript module (class) to be used with CommonJS, AMD or neither

Tags: javascript, amd, commonjs

I have created a simple Javascript module. I'd like this to be available to CommonJS implementations, AMD implementations and global ()

Here is my class:

```
function Geolocation( callback ){
    this._latitude          = null;
    this._longitude         = null;
    this._accuracy          = null;
}

Geolocation.prototype = {
    //prototype definitions in here
}
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? An exhaustive google search has not yielded any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function (global, factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) define(factory); //AMD
    else if (typeof module === "object") module.exports = factory(); //CommonJS
    else global.Geolocation = factory(); // for example browser (global will be window object)
}(this, function () {

var Geolocation = function( callback ){
    this._latitude          = null;
    this._longitude         = null;
    this._accuracy          = null;
}

Geolocation.prototype = {
    //prototype definitions in here
}

return Geolocation;

}));
```